# When using Java ternary operator or Math functions, is the returned value always up to date?

Tags: java, math, ternary-operator

When using Java ternary operator or Math functions, is the returned value always up to date, or does the statement have to be reevaluated whenever I need an updated value?

Considering:

```
a = myBoolean? 1: 2;
a = Math.min(x, y);
```

Does the values of "a" would change dynamically like it would in...

```
a = x + y;
```

...when "x" or "y" change?

Comment: Why do you think either way?

Comment: What do you mean by "change dinamycally" ?

Comment: It's simply a shorted cut `if-else` statement, which is evaluated every time it's executed.  I suggest you write a little test code and see for yourself ;)

Comment: Statements in Java are executed *in sequence*. There is no automatic "reevaluating" of previous expressions when variables change. This is true for both the `?:` and `+` operators, as well as any other operator.

Comment: Thanks everybody, this was really enlightening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *current value* of evaluating the variable (expression) is passed to the method as arguments. The same happens when variable (expression) are used as operator operands<sup>1</sup>.

Changing the original variables' value later - after the code has executed - has no effect on the [already complete] computation. The original expressions have already been evaluated (to *values*) as input and the resulting *value* is assigned to the variable.

This is also known as [eager evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eager_evaluation):

> In eager evaluation, *an expression is evaluated as soon as it is bound to a variable* [or supplied to a method or used with an operator] ..
>
> .. Imperative programming languages [like Java], where the order of execution is implicitly defined by the source code organization, almost always use eager evaluation.

---

<sup>1</sup> The ternary/conditional (`?:`), logical-and (`&&`), and logical-or (`||`) operators also apply [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).